# Query dsl - How to write having clause

Tags: java, spring-boot, querydsl

I am new to Java and Querydsl. I have searched so much to get how to write the below query in query dsl. end up with nothing.Can any one please help.

```
SELECT * FROM `library_user_product` GROUP by user_id HAVING max(product_id)
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [link](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/group#:%7E:text=all%20JPA%20implementations.-,GROUP%20BY%20with%20HAVING,filtered%20using%20the%20HAVING%20clause.&text=The%20HAVING%20clause%20stands%20as,passed%20to%20the%20SELECT%20clause.) it has  examples for the group by, having and other function in respect to JPA

sample:

```
SELECT c.currency, SUM(c.population) FROM Country c
WHERE 'Europe' MEMBER OF c.continents
GROUP BY c.currency
HAVING COUNT(c) > 1
```